# How to print a percentage value?

Tags: python

Given a float between 0 and 1, how to print it as a percentage?

For example, `1/3` should print as `33%`.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

Since Python 3.0, [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) support a [percentage presentation type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> f"{1/3:.0%}"
'33%'
>>> "{:.0%}".format(1/3)
'33%'
>>> format(1/3, ".0%")
'33%'
```

> Percentage. Multiplies the number by 100 and displays in fixed (`'f'`) format, followed by a percent sign.

The `.0` part of the format spec `.0%` indicates that you want zero digits of precision after the decimal point, because with `f"{1/3:%}"` you would get the string `'33.333333%'`.

It works with integers, floats, and [decimals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal). See [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Comment: Is `float(1)` really more pythonic than `1.`?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, I do not know, if it's more pythonic. At least it is something you stumble over while reading the code. I think with Python 3 and *real* division by default this irritation is gone.

Comment: Indeed. I wonder why Guido didn't implement real division from the very start... Rounding 1/3 to 0 should be [explicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ "Explicit is better than implicit.") after all...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Probably because in earlier times, Python was closer to C than nowadays.

Comment: In Python 2, I'd use `1.0` instead of `float(1)` or `1.`. IMHO it's less obtrusive than the former and not as subtle as the latter.

Comment: so in f-string style it will be `f"{1/3.0:.0%}"`

Comment: Well-explained and handy answer, especially for reporting numerical strings as real numbers.

Answer (score 223):

There is a way more convenient 'percent'-formatting option for the `.format()` format method:

```
>>> '{:.1%}'.format(1/3.0)
'33.3%'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with old school `"%.1f"` formatting?

Comment: Little bit "less convenient", but, yes! Like suggested above `print("%.1f%%" % (100 * 1.0/3))`

Comment: This is the best answer because it doesn't require a multiplication by 100.  Rather it takes advantage of the fact that `format` already knows how to print percentages!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is much more Pythonic, using built-in capabilities to eliminate the meaningless implementation detail that a multiplication by 100 would be.

Comment: so in f-string style it will be `f"{1/3.0:.1%}"`

Answer (score 95):

Just to add Python 3 f-string solution

```
prob = 1.0/3.0
print(f"{prob:.0%}")  # 33%
print(f"{prob:.2%}")  # 33.33%
```

Comment: Could someone explain what this does? Thanks

Comment: @F.M https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: it should be like this instead: print(f"{prob:.0f}%")

Comment: @MichalK No, it should not. When your number is a fraction then you need to use f"{prob:.0%}", to auto-convert to percentage.

Answer (score 93):

Just for the sake of completeness, since I noticed no one suggested this simple approach:

```
>>> print("%.0f%%" % (100 * 1.0/3))
33%
```

Details:

- `%.0f` stands for "*print a float with 0 decimal places*", so `%.2f` would print `33.33`
- `%%` prints a literal `%`. A bit cleaner than your original `+'%'`
- `1.0` instead of `1` takes care of coercing the division to float, so no more `0.0`

Comment: note: 100.0 * 1/3 -> ok, 100.0 * (1/3) -> 0.0 not ok

Comment: @martialdidit: I'm aware of that, that's why my answer does *not* have parenthesis in `1/3`. Evaluation order is intentional: `100.0 * 1 / 3 => 100.0 / 3 => 0.33...`

Comment: In any case, I've moved  the coercion from the `100` to the `1`, to make things clear.

Comment: Beg your pardon, @RuggeroTurra? This _is_ formatting, in the broad sense that it _transforms_ an input to display as a string. Please note the OP never required the use of `.format()`, and `%`-formatting, also known as _string interpolation_ in Python, is a perfectly valid alternative.

Comment: With % you are formatting a float to a string. Not a float to a percentage-string. The multiplication by 100 is done by hand, not by the %. I think the only correct solution which only uses formatting is with {:.0%}

Comment: @RuggeroTurra, I agree, and that's why years ago I upvoted both [this 2014 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23764798/624066) _and_ its most-upvoted comment _"This is the best answer"_. The currently accepted answer was edited in 2018 to use this too. None of these answers existed in 2013 when I wrote my humble alternative, which was a perfectly acceptable one in the Python 2 era.

Answer (score 41):

You are dividing integers then converting to float. Divide by floats instead.

As a bonus, use the awesome string formatting methods described here: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

To specify a percent conversion and precision.

```
>>> float(1) / float(3)
[Out] 0.33333333333333331

>>> 1.0/3.0
[Out] 0.33333333333333331

>>> '{0:.0%}'.format(1.0/3.0) # use string formatting to specify precision
[Out] '33%'

>>> '{percent:.2%}'.format(percent=1.0/3.0)
[Out] '33.33%'
```

A great gem!

Answer (score 4):

Then you'd want to do this instead:

```
print str(int(1.0/3.0*100))+'%'
```

The `.0` denotes them as floats and `int()` rounds them to integers afterwards again.

Comment: i know this is from 2011 but ... `int()` does not round. e.g. `int(1.9) != 2`.  Rounding can be done like so - `round(1.9,0) == 2`

Comment: `int()` certainly does round _down_ the number. My example does exactly what I meant it to do; cutting off the digits since that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: Stockoverflow is great - a couple of year and still a response. Thank you. However, for the sake of completeness, I want to clarify. `int()` drops the digits. It does not round down. Rounding implies it does something with the digits. The end result is the same though; in that sense, I see your point. Also, the OP does not clarify what he/she wants to do with the digits has 33.333... does round to 33. Thank you for responding to my comment and have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
ratio = round(1/3, 2) 
print(f"{ratio} %")

output: 0.33 %
```

Comment: ratio = round(1/3, 4) * 100 works better for me, but thanks :-)

Comment: 1/3 = 33%, not 0.33%

Comment: @MestreLion I caused confusion here, 1/3 is 0.33 then I added % sign after the 0.33 -> 0.33 %.

Answer (score -1):

this is what i did to get it working, worked like a charm

```
divideing = a / b
percentage = divideing * 100
print(str(float(percentage))+"%")
```