# Python programing - exiting the loop and displaying score

Tags: python

really need some help with my ongoing "project" as I am a total novice - not just in Python, but the programing itself - have been working with Python for only a week.

What I'm trying to create is a little "Quiz", menu works fine, it was the simplest thing to create, same goes for choice nr 2 in the menu, exiting the quiz, but I have some problems with the  rest of the code. What I need to be fixed is that after every time player answers a question he is prompted with a question if he/she wants to continue playing, if yes ("ja") the player gets a new random question, if not the current score (in percentage) is displayed and the program shuts down. Random questions are working fine,continuing is working fine, but exiting the quiz and score is still a problem and I can't get it right, maybe it's just a simple mistake, but somehow I just can't find it.

Thank you in advance!

PS. With some unknown reason the hole code wont display properly in the code box, so I'm posting just a problem "area" of the code.

```
while aqpool[0]:
    shuffle (aqpool)
    numRight = 0



    for question, rightAnswer in aqpool:
        answer = input(question + " ")

        playAgain = "ja"
        playStop = "nej"

        if answer == rightAnswer:
            print ("RÄTT SVAR!")

            numRight = numRight + 1


            if playAgain == "ja" or playAgain == "j":

                print("Vill du försätta spela? (ja eller nej)")
                playAgain = str(input())
                continue

            if playStop == "nej" or playStop == "n":
                total = numRight / len(aqpool) * 100
                print ("Du hade ",total, "% rätt!")
                playStop = str(input())
                break                                

        else:


            print("FEL SVAR! Rätta svaret är: " + rightAnswer + "\n")

            if playAgain == "ja" or playAgain == "j":
                print ("Vill du försätta spela? (ja eller nej)")
                playAgain = str(input())

            if playStop == "nej" or playStop == "n":
                total = numRight / len(aqpool) * 100
                print ("Du hade ", total, "% rätt!")
                playStop = str(input())
                break
```

Comment: Please come up with a more specific title. Every question in SO is a problem with code!

Comment: Don't know how to edit title, and as said, total novice in programing so it's not that easy to specify the problem within the 3-4 words in the ttitle.

Comment: Clicl on the `edit` link below the question.

Comment: Basically, you want the loop to end when the user wants to stop playing. So your loop condition should reflect this. e.g. : `while userWantToContinue or noMoreQuestion:`

Comment: Questions are supposed to loop (even those answered) as long as the user wants to keep playing, so the problem is exiting the loop and displaying the score in percentage at the exit. =)

Comment: Ok, so the loop condition is simply : `while userWantToContinue:`. Regarding the score, it should be display outside the loop.

Comment: So should I create a new loop "while userWantToContinue:" inside the existing loop? the existing loop is created for "random/shuffle" questions/answers?

Comment: You don't need to create an additional loop. You should instead modify the top level while loop. Otherwise, with the `break` statement you only breaking the inner loop (`for`)

Comment: I think you mean "fortsätta" though (-:

Comment: Yeah, saw that now.. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userWantToContinue = True
while aqpool[0] and userWantToContinue:
    shuffle (aqpool)
    numRight = 0

    for question, rightAnswer in aqpool:
        answer = raw_input(question + " ")

        if answer == rightAnswer:
            print ("RÄTT SVAR!")

            numRight = numRight + 1

        else:
            print("FEL SVAR! Rätta svaret är: " + rightAnswer + "\n")


        print("Vill du försätta spela? (ja eller nej)")
        userWantToContinue = str(raw_input()) not in ('n', 'nej')
        if not userWantToContinue:
            break

    total = numRight / len(aqpool) * 100
    print ("Du hade %s%% rätt!" % total)
```

Comment: Just what I needed, thank you!! But there is only one problem, after each answered question when the user is prompted if he wants to continue playing even by choosing not to game still the quiz still goes on?

Comment: fixed. Added a conditional `break` statement

Comment: Thank you!! It's really not easy to place things on the right spot when just started programing. Hopefully it will get easier with time. =) But really sorry to do this again, but there are still some problems with the score, questions that are in the "question pool" that I leave unanswered by quitting the game are counted as the wrong answers, so if I answer 2 out of 4 questions in my "question pool" and both are correct answers, by quitting the game I get only 50% correct?

Comment: Score calculation is another topic. But your concern is probably that you should use `float` type instead of `interger` when dividing. see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-show-percentage-in-python

Comment: It displays it right, so the float should not be the problem, the problem is that when it's counting total amount of correct and incorrect answers, all the answers in the "question pool" that are unanswered are taken as the incorrect ones so the user doesn't get the right score. :/

Comment: ok, so just count the number of asked questions. Then use that count instead of `len(aqpool)`

Comment: Just added a little bit of code and it works now, thank you once again for your time and help. =)