# Python - Psutil as percentage

Tags: python

I have a task manmager made in python and it use wx to make it a gui interface, but I use psutil to get percentage of usage of memory for a process the problem is it puts it in decimal and everything I have tried causes it to not display processes at all. I have tried adding .percent after some stuff that displays the percentage but that didnt work heres part of the code that gets the data to display:

```
def updateDisplay(self):

    pids = psutil.get_pid_list()
    for pid in pids:

        try:
            p = psutil.Process(pid)
            new_proc = Process(p.name,
                               str(p.pid),
                               p.exe,
                               p.username,
                               str(p.get_cpu_percent()),
                               str(p.get_memory_percent())
                               )
            self.procs.append(new_proc)
        except:
            pass

    self.setProcs()
```

if you need the whole code just let me know. 
so once more let me summerize what I would like I want to display get_memory_percent as a percent instead of a decimal.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5306787/27604 to convert your decimal to a %

Comment: not sure how i would do that though if i wanted to do that i dont think it would work as im using another module to print the percentage in a list(object list view)

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is. What exact data are you getting and what shape do you need it to be? Give us some examples, data types, etc, not just "it puts it in decimal". (What puts what in what?)

Comment: i use psutil to print out in object list view all the processes and the amount of memory being used i want it to present it in percentage instead of decimal

Comment: ok i got it to got to a percent but how would i round it? i now have 'code' str(p.getmem_percent() *100)'code'

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the method is already calling the result as a percentage, just not in the format required so `/100` is pointless here.

Your ultimate goal is unclear, so i have a few options for you. If your goal is to print a rounded, 2 decimal string, with the percentage symbol following the string, this will do it:

`"{:.2%}".format(round(p.get_cpu_percent(),2))`

However, if you are after no trailing numbers after the decimal point:

`"{:.0%}".format(round(p.get_cpu_percent(),2))`

And finally, if you are after no percentage sign, just numbers:

`"{:.2}".format(round(p.get_cpu_percent(),2))`

Try and be as specific as possible, this will increase your chances of getting a timely, accurate answer!