# Converting Decimal to %

Tags: python, formatting, decimal, percentage

So I have looked at the post here:
[how to show Percentage in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-show-percentage-in-python) and used the solution.

```
S = 'ftp'
"{0:.0f}%".format(S.count('f') / 9 * 100)
```

The desired output is *11%*, but when I run the code using the  format specified I get *"0%"* instead of the 11% that I want. Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: The linked question actually explains this already pretty well. What part didn’t you understand?

Comment: I understand everything, its just that my expected output wasn`t right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a percentage, you should just use the percent formatter directly:

```
>>> '{:.0%}'.format(S.count('f') / 9)
'11%'
```

As others already noted, Python 2 will use integer division if both arguments are integers, so you can just make the constant a float instead:

```
>>> '{:.0%}'.format(S.count('f') / 9.)
'11%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the format statement, just the arithmetic - your integer division makes S.count('f') / 9 return 0.  Changing your 9 to 9.0 should work.

Answer (score 0):

It works in Python 3 but for Python 2 you need atleast one float number to get float result for /

You can add . (dot) to 9 to have float number.

```
S = 'ftp'
"{0:.0f}%".format(S.count('f') / 9. * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because (in Python 2) you're using integer division where `3 / 9` gives you zero.

You can switch to floating point division:

```
"{0:.0f}%".format(S.count('f') / 9.0 * 100)
```

and you'll see why that works in the following transcript:

```
>>> 3/9
0

>>> 3/9.0
0.3333333333333333
```

Alternatively, you can rearrange your operations so that you multiply first:

```
"{0:.0f}%".format(S.count('f') * 100 / 9)
```