# How to turn input number into a percentage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ("How much does your meal cost")

meal = 0
tip = 0
tax = 0.0675

action = input( "Type amount of meal ")

if action.isdigit():
    meal = (action)
    print (meal)

tips = input(" type the perentage of tip you want to give ")


if tips.isdigit():
    tip = tips 
    print(tip)
```

I have written this but I do not know how to get

```
print(tip)
```

to be a percentage when someone types a number in.

Comment: a percentage is just `number/100`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a percentage value in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-print-a-percentage-value-in-python)

Answer (score 22):

```
>>> "{:.1%}".format(0.88)
'88.0%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your usage of `input()` rather than `raw_input()`, I assume you are using `python3`.

You just need to convert the user input into a floating point number, and divide by 100.

```
print ("How much does your meal cost")

meal = 0
tip = 0
tax = 0.0675

action = input( "Type amount of meal ")

if action.isdigit():
    meal = float(action)

tips = input(" type the perentage of tip you want to give ")

if tips.isdigit():
    tip = float(tips)  / 100 * meal
    print(tip)
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, You are correct that converting to an `int` will also work, but suppose the user decided they wanted to give `15.5%` tip?

Comment: scratch that I thought you meant for division reasons. a while try/except might  be  a better option though

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, A very reasonable point, but I'm trying to address the question with as little change to the user's original code as possible.

Comment: well +1 anyway it does answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

It will be

```
print "Tip = %.2f%%" % (100*float(tip)/meal)
```

The end `%%` prints the percent sign. The number `(100*float(tip)/meal)` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We're assuming that it's a number the user is putting in.  We want to make sure that the number is a valid percentage that the program can work with.  I would recommend anticipating both expressions of a percentage from the user.  So the user might type in `.155` or `15.5` to represent 15.5%.  A run-of-the-mill if statement is one way to see to that. (assuming you've already converted to float)

```
if tip > 1:
    tip = tip / 100
```

Alternatively, you could use what's called a ternary expression to handle this case.  In your case, it would look something like this:

```
tip = (tip / 100) if tip > 1 else tip
```

There's [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) you could check out to find out more about ternary syntax.