# Precise Multiplication without floating point arithmetic

Tags: python, precision, multiplication

How can I get the exact result of a multiplication?

Python tells me that `0.017 * 3` equals `0.051000000000000004`. Is there any command to make python print `0.051`?

Answer (score 3):

Fractional numeric literals in Python have the type [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), which is represented in binary. Use the [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) type for base 10 arithmetic.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> print(Decimal('0.017') * 3)
0.051
```

Comment: I get Decimal('0.05100000000000000366373598126')

Comment: @Jerther Did you perhaps not type the quotes around `'0.017'`? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: You're right, I left the quotes out. I always thought it was a quick convenience constructor that just parses the string. Well obviously it's not :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me `Decimal(0.1433) * 100=Decimal('14.33000000000000107025499574')`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the expected number of significant digits the operation should output, you can use the built-in rounding function in python (in this case 3).

```
>>> round(0.017 * 3, 3)
0.051
```

Comment: The question is "How do you get the exact result in a multiplication". This answer does not answer that question. You're actually adding imprecision. You should address why you're offering a rounding solution at the beginning of your answer.

Comment: If that's the case then add that assumption as a precursor to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when wanting to display percentages in fstring text and there was a nice solution using fstrings formatting. It's technically the same as the `round()` solution but is a lot easier to maintain than having to add the round function to every percentage in fstrings.

```
number = 0.1433
print(f"the percent is {number*100}%")
print(f"the percent is {number:.1%}")

the percent is 14.330000000000002%
the percent is 14.3%
```

See [How to print a percentage value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-print-a-percentage-value) for additional details.