# Python: How to print percentage

Tags: python, printing

I have a question about printing.

When I am printing:

"Work in progress(**0%**)"

How do I only edit the bold part?

Comment: Where do you print it? Command line or GUI?

Comment: @Alex.S In python GUI. The Shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show Percentage in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-show-percentage-in-python)

Comment: @Guoliang He's not asking how to print a percentage. He wants to edit his last print statement on command line

Comment: JKC - Can you please explain your question? What would you like to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: Exactly what @HassanMehmood Said.

Comment: JKC - Can you please explain your question? What would you like to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print in one line dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Comment: ...specifically, see the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249684/4116239) about terminal control codes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it's clear _exactly_ what you want to do, what you've tried, and what didn't work (or what you didn't understand).  Also, search Stack Overflow's to see if your question has already been asked.

Comment: I was asking how to edit the bold part while printing..

Answer (score 2):

If printing on the command line you can use:

```
import time
print "Work in progress( 0%%)", # Python 2 print without newline
for work_done in range(10):
    print "\b\b\b\b\b%2d%%)" % work_done, # Backspace then overwrite
    time.sleep(1)
```

This will print your base line and then backspace each time that it is rewritten.
N.B. for python 3 you would need `print(whatever, end=None)`

Comment: doesn't work for me on python 2.7

Comment: @HassanMehmood What do you get?

Comment: I get bunch of numbers in a row. But when I added a time.sleep, it works completely fine.

Comment: I would expect there to be some work going on in the `work_done` loop which will give the terminal time to catch up so you probably will not need a `time.sleep`

Comment: Yeah right, but for debugging purposes I added to visually observe the change.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.format`:

```
 print "Work in progress({0}%)".format(some_variable_holding_percentage)
```

Comment: He's not asking how to print a percentage. He wants to edit his last print statement on command line

Answer (score 0):

```
percentage = 15
print "Work in progress({:d}%)".format(percentage)
```

output:

```
Work in progress(15%)
```

Comment: He's not asking how to print a percentage. He wants to edit his last print statement on command line

Comment: Thanks much, but I think this will print "Work in progress" several times.
How do I only change the percentage?

Comment: This will print "Work in progress(15%)" only once.

Comment: JKC - Did you try to execute it?