# In Python how can we combine the formatting mechanism for both strings and a percentage?

Tags: python, string, format, percentage

In python, I want to format a string combining two strings with a percentage. From this post [how to show Percentage in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-show-percentage-in-python) I know to format a percentage we can use

```
>>> print "{:.0%}".format(1/3)
33%
```

In my case I want to do something like

```
>>> print "{0}/{1} = {:.0%}".format('1', '3', 1/3)
1/3 = 33%
```

But the above code returns

```
ValueError: cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering
```

So what's the proper way to format the string like this? Thank you!

Comment: Generally a good idea to check the official documentation first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it saying is that you are providing numbered placement for the first two arguments `{0}` and `{1}`, then suddenly there is one without a positioning number, so it cannot extrapolate which one to put there. (As when numbered, they can be in any order or repeat) So you need to make sure that last item is also numbered.

```
print "{0}/{1} = {2:.0%}".format('1', '3', 1/3)
```

Alternatively, let it figure the positioning of the format arguments out:

```
print("{}/{} = {:.0%}".format('1', '3', 1/3))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works as a charm!!! I didn't realize before that colon is the place we should put the positioning number! And the second method is much simpler! Learned!

Answer (score 1):

**In Python2.7**

```
>>> print "{:.0%}".format(1/3)
0%
```

I guess it should be unsupported percentage

**In python3.5**

can work normally

1. with positional parameters

```
>>> print("{}/{} = {:.0%}".format('1', '3', 1/3))
1/3 = 33%
```

2. no positional parameters

```
>>> print("{0}/{1} = {2:.0%}".format('1', '3', 1/3))
1/3 = 33%
```

so, two ways to write can not be mixed

Comment: Thank you sunnky! I got it!