# How can I format this output to have a %?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to format the output to have a percentage, where the `labScore=score(labPercent, labWeight)` is?

Here's my sample:

```
def score(earnedPercent, overallWeight):
    scorePercent = earnedPercent * overallWeight
    scorePercent = scorePercent % 7
    return scorePercent

def grade(gradePercent):
   if gradePercent >=90 and gradePercent <= 100:
      letterGrade="A"
   elif gradePercent >=75 and gradePercent <= 90:
      letterGrade="B"
   elif gradePercent >= 60 and gradePercent <= 75:
      letterGrade = "C"
   elif gradePercent >= 50 and gradePercent <= 60:
      letterGrade = "D"
   elif gradePercent < 50:
      letterGrade = "F"
   return letterGrade

labWeight = 0.20
labPercent=int(input("What is your lab percent so far (-1 if no labs yet)?: "))
labScore=score(labPercent, labWeight)

assignmentWeight = 0.10
assignmentPercent=int(input("What is your assignment percent so far (-1 if no assignment yet?: "))
assignmentScore=score(assignmentPercent, assignmentWeight)

examWeight = 0.70
examPercent=int(input("What is your exam percent so far (-1 if no exams yet)?: "))
examScore=score(examPercent, examWeight)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show Percentage in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-show-percentage-in-python)

Comment: What's the point of the modulo operation in line 3? (Also, check your indentation; line 4 should be triggering a syntax error).

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis, ...huh? The only context where I know that a `%` sign in Python needs to be escaped is in a format string, and in that context, the correct escaping format is to double them, not to precede with a backslash. And I don't see anywhere in this question where it calls for *either* of those escaping methods at all.

Comment: You are getting closer, but what is the `grade()` function doing here? You are still not calling it and still there must be an error calling `score()`. You must run the code you post yourself and then also include the full Traceback.

Comment: @b_c I think so, however my question is _how_ do I format, and where do I format it?

Comment: @quamarana, the traceback says in line 42, `labScore=score(labPercent, labWeight) nameError: name 'labWeight' is not defined`

Comment: Ok, so what should `labWeight` be and how should it be processed by the `score()` function?

Comment: @quamrana, that would be the lab weight of 20% so do I need to create a new string to multiply the percentage to process it?

Comment: @katie: It looks like `labWeight` must be a numeric value.

Comment: What strings? You are dealing with `int`s in your program, and that's the right thing to do. You can have `labWeight = 20` just before the first `input()`.

Comment: @katie: following the answer from martineau, I think you're ready to ask another question (press the `Ask Question` button) which should cover calling your `grade()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print it out followed by a literal `%` character as shown. Note I also removed the `scorePercent = scorePercent % 7` you have in your version of the function because there's no need for it.

```
import sys

def score(earnedPercent, overallWeight):
    scorePercent = earnedPercent * overallWeight
    return scorePercent

def grade(gradePercent):
   if gradePercent >=90 and gradePercent <= 100:
      letterGrade="A"
   elif gradePercent >=75 and gradePercent <= 90:
      letterGrade="B"
   elif gradePercent >= 60 and gradePercent <= 75:
      letterGrade = "C"
   elif gradePercent >= 50 and gradePercent <= 60:
      letterGrade = "D"
   elif gradePercent < 50:
      letterGrade = "F"
   return letterGrade

labWeight = 0.20
labPercent=int(input("What is your lab percent so far (-1 if no labs yet)?: "))
labScore=score(labPercent, labWeight)
if labPercent > -1:
    labScore=score(labPercent, labWeight)
    print('labScore: {}%'.format(labScore))
    sys.exit()  # If you want to quit the program completely.
```

Sample run:

```
What is your lab percent so far (-1 if no labs yet)?: 69
labScore: 13.8%
```

Comment: katie: You've changed your question, so my answer isn't quite right any more.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is so helpful! What can I do about the -1 in the brackets or would that result into a zero if I put in -1 either way?

Comment: Again that's another question.

Comment: @quamrana, I'm asking in relation to the lab score.

Comment: Yes, and its worth asking a separate question about it.

Comment: @quamrana: While I generally agree with your comments, it just doesn't seem that important at this point. Katie, consider this answer a gift, but please try to ask better questions in the future and don't change them so much, especially after someone has already answered.