# How to isolate a single digit in a decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to isolate a single digit inside of a decimal in order to display a formatted percentage.

I am getting:

```
result = 8 / 10
print(result)
#Output: 0.8
```

I want to solely isolate the 8 so I can print:

```
print(f"The answer is {result}%")
#Output: The answer is 80%
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Why just multiplying doesnt work? `print(f"The answer is {int(result*100)}%")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a percentage value in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-print-a-percentage-value-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, .8 is 80% not 8%.

to format a decimal as a percentage use `print(f'{result:.0%}')` this will produce `80%`

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean strip the "0."?
If so, you can use:

```py
print(str(result * 100) + '%')
```

P.S. 0.8 means 80%, not 8%.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I guess I was just looking for an overcomplicated answer for a simple solution.

Comment: Sometimes we just can't find out a simple solutionThe Zen Of Python really makes sense`There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.`