# Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Tags: python

I’m working on a school problem to calculate percentage. The problem reads:

1. Write a function called percent. This function will calculate the percentage of one number relative to another.
2. The function will accept two parameters: num1(int) and num2(int)
3. The function will return the calculated percentage as a string (str).
4. Example:

```
>>> print(percent(155, 500))
“31.0%”
```

My current code reads as follows:

```
def percent(num1, num2):
    return (num1 / num2) * 100

print(percent(155, 500))
```

This gives me 31.0, but I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong to make it print as a string, as everything I’ve tried has given me an error code.

Comment: The obvious answer is:  `return str(num1/num2*100)`.  The quotes won't print.  Your example is wrong.

Comment: Try looking at what happens if you call [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) on your result.

Comment: @TimRoberts as far as I understand the problem is the percent sign

Comment: @Stephanie What exactly did you try and what were the error codes you were talking about?

Comment: Are you asking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306756/how-to-print-a-percentage-value

Comment: If formatting is the issue, you can use f-strings like `return f"{num1/num2*100}%"`

Comment: @mkrieger1 so far I have gotten the result I thought I needed with @tdelaney’s answer, but now it tells me “ expected: percent(9,45)=20%, Actual: 20%”. At this point I’m not sure what it’s asking me to do anymore

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a `float` and `print` displays the string value of that float. Since you want a different string, you'll have to do the formatting yourself. Traditionally you'd do that with the `str.format` method,  but python has implemented f-strings, a way to format strings using names resolved from the program.

```
>>> def percent(num1, num2):
...     retval = (num1 / num2) * 100
...     return f'“{retval}%”'
... 
>>> print(percent(155, 500))
“31.0%”
```

Comment: This helped me get the expected result, however it still tells me I “failed the following test” and I’m not sure why. It says “expected: percent(9,45)=20%, actual: 20.0%

Does this mean I need to format it so there is no decimal?

Comment: @StephanieKrajewski - Yes. You could convert to an integer `return f'“{int(retval)}%”' and loose the `.`. But that would mess up the "30.0%" example. I don't know how you could satisfy both requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make the function return your output as a string:

```py
def percent(num1, num2):
   return str((num1/num2)*100)
```

Then when you print it, it should return that it is a string when you check it using `type()`:

```
print(percent(155, 500))
# To check whether it returns the *right* answer (output: 31.0)

print( type(percent(155, 500)) )
# To check whether it returns the answer *right* (output: <class 'str'>)
```